# Centering InfoWindow Google Map IFrame

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to center the pop up window (info window) on a google map iFrame to make sure that it does not get cut off?

WOuld it be easier for me to use the Google Map API instead of iFrame? If so, is there an API call that would give me the same information by default on a the infoWIndow?

Note: I have tried using Google Map API and I prefer this over using iFrame. The only downside is that I do not get the extra information that comes with using google map iFrame. It looks like I need to populate this window with HTML by myself.

Comment: Default Infowindow bubbles can be pretty large. I would suggest using API as you would get more control over your map, such as creating custom markers and styling InfoWindows with CSS. They are pretty easy to create if you invest 30 minutes of your time into reading the official docs.

Comment: what about getting the same information that you get from using an iFrame? is it possible with API? It seems like i need to use Places API to get the same information and I need to turn that JSON into UI HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw here's a good example of how to create a custom InfoWindow.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

You can use any html such as custom headers, divs and links

And here's the Placed API with Google Maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way for me to just get the same infoWindow that I see when I use iFrame but on Map API. I don't want to write my own custom HTML for the infoWindow if there is a default one available.

Comment: Hi denniss you can achive that by clicking the "Customize and preview embedded map" link in the google map area when you click on the link icon beside the printer icon..